# Optimization of list's sublist

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, python-3.x

the problem is to find total number of sub-lists from a given list that doesn't contain numbers greater than a specified upper bound number say `right` and sub lists max number should be greater than a lower bound say `left` .Suppose my list is: `x=[2, 0, 11, 3, 0]` and upper bound for sub-list elements is `10` and lower bound is `1` then my sub-lists can be `[[2],[2,0],[3],[3,0]]` as sub lists are always continuous .My script runs well and produces correct output but needs some optimization

```
def query(sliced,left,right):
    end_index=0
    count=0
    leng=len(sliced)
    for i in range(leng):
        stack=[]
        end_index=i

        while(end_index<leng and sliced[end_index]<=right):

            stack.append(sliced[end_index])
            if max(stack)>=left:
                count+=1
            end_index+=1

    print (count)

origin=[2,0,11,3,0]
left=1
right=10
query(origin,left,right)
```

`output:4`

Comment: What is your optimization target, and where is your current performance in relation to your target?  Also, are additional modules acceptable?

Comment: @andrew_reece my script execution time is at least 1.5 times then the ideal execution time,Any builtin module would do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can streamline by dropping the use of `append`, and ignoring values in your for-loop that are automatically disqualified.  Benchmarking shows these steps reduce execution time by about 2x.

Original:

```
%%timeit

origin=[2,0,11,3,0]
left=1
right=10
query(origin,left,right) 
# 3.6 µs ± 950 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

New version:

```
def query2(sliced,left,right):
    count = 0
    leng = len(sliced)
    for i in range(leng):
        if sliced[i] <= right:
            stack_ct = 0
            end_index = i
            found_max = False
            while(end_index < leng and sliced[end_index] <= right):
                if not found_max:
                    found_max = sliced[end_index] >= left
                end_index += 1
                stack_ct += 1
            if found_max:
                count += stack_ct
    return count
```

Benchmarking:

```
%%timeit

origin=[2,0,11,3,0]
left=1
right=10
query2(origin,left,right)
# 1.83 µs ± 41.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```